# Instead of Scala Map objects, can we use any other proper objects for below type of structure?(Case Class)

Tags: arrays, scala, object, mapping, case-class

I have just shifted to the scala and there I have the Map object as per the below structure.

```
object report {

  def report_sn(flag : Boolean = false) : Map[String, Map[String,Any]]  = Map(
      "100"->Map("reportName"->"XYZ",
      "queryColumns"->Array("title", "startDate", "endDate"),
      "groupBy"->Array(),
      "groupByFunctions"->Array(),
      "query"->("SELECT * "+
        "FROM "+
        " abctable limit 10 "),
      "queryParams"->Array(),
      "xmlTemplate"->"xyz",
      "processFunction"->"pqrFun"
    ),
    "101"-> Map("reportName"->"XYZ1",
      "queryColumns"->Array("title", "startDate", "endDate"),
      "groupBy"->Array(),
      "groupByFunctions"->Array(),
      "query"->("SELECT * "+
        "FROM "+
        " abc1table limit 10 "),
      "queryParams"->Array(),
      "xmlTemplate"->"xyz1",
      "processFunction"->"pqr1Fun"
  )
)
```

Like this, I have 1000s of query details in this map object.

I am looking for a way to use some other objects to make it more readable and understandable code.

Comment: Create a `case class` for the inner group, also use `List` instead of `Array`

Comment: Can you post a sample code for the same in the answer section @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As commented by @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez, you could use a `case class` instead of a `Map[String, Any]` and it will be more readable and better typed.

Something like this:

```scala
  case class Report(reportName: String,
                    queryColumns: List[String],
                    groupBy: List[String],
                    groupByFunctions: List[String],
                    query: String,
                    queryParams: List[String],
                    xmlTemplate: String,
                    processFunction: String
  )

  def report_sn(flag: Boolean = false): Map[String, Report] =
    Map(
      "100" -> Report(
        reportName = "XYZ",
        queryColumns = List("title", "startDate", "endDate"),
        groupBy = List(),
        groupByFunctions = List(),
        query = "SELECT * FROM abctable limit 10",
        queryParams = List(),
        xmlTemplate = "xyz",
        processFunction = "pqrFun"
      ),
      "101" -> Report(???)
    )
```